# Does android support APIs for implementing RTP,RTSP for VoIP and PTT Project?

Tags: android, voip, multimedia, rtsp, rtp

I am going to make a PTT project on Android. Could you tell me how deep Android supports Voice and Multimedia API (such as RTP,RTSP,VoIP) for developers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`MediaPlayer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) supports playing `rtsp://..` URLs. Audio and Video are supported. Check [media format support](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) to see which codecs are supported.

MediaPlayer internally automatically handles RTSP and RTP, so there is not much you need to handle. OTOH it does not give any low-level control over this process.

About VoIP: Android only consumes RTSP/RTP streams, but does not create/publish them. So this is one-way only.

Android 2.3 (Gingerbread) is said to have support for [SIP-based VoIP](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3.html#api).

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply,

But if I want to create an stream(RTP/RTSP), what should I do?

Comment: I'm thinking of looking into some of the opensource C/C++ libraries to see how difficult it is to build them with the NDK. That seems to be your only option, aside from implementing your own RTP/RTSP server in Java.

Answer (score 3):

Use AudioTrack\AudioRecord APIs for streaming audio recording and playback. They allow you to deal with raw audio frames.

RTP packets are pretty straightforward - it's just a packet that contains some minimal header data and a raw audio frame. It is easy to implement - check out SipDroid for a reference implementation of RTP packets.