# How to resolve "The import android.net.rtp cannot be resolved"?

Tags: android, android-manifest, live-streaming

Hi i am developing live video stream in android with wowza media server. I follow this link http://spydroid-ipcamera.googlecode.com/svn/ . I created all the things. Now my problem is i got an error in GenericAudioStream.java class as

```
    import android.net.rtp.AudioCodec;
    import android.net.rtp.AudioGroup;
    import android.net.rtp.AudioStream;
    import android.net.rtp.RtpStream;
```

The import android.net.rtp cannot be resolved. How can i resolved it? Can anybody help me to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: press `CTRL + SHIFT + O`  and put all jar file in `libs` folder if you have.

Comment: but i have android2.3 device only to execute this application. So i mentioned  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>  in manifest.xml file. Is it possible???

Comment: The classes in `android.net.rtp.*` are only available for `android:minSdkVersion="12"` or higher. If you just want to play back an RTSP (RTP, SDP) stream, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/4416773/180740

Comment: is this final or any alternate solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`android.net.rtp.*` package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/package-summary.html) is only available since API level 12 (Android 3.1.x Honeycomb MR1), so your app would need `android:minSdkVersion="12"` or higher.

If you just want to play back an RTSP (RTP, SDP) stream, take a look at: [Does android support APIs for implementing RTP,RTSP for VoIP and PTT Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416639/does-android-support-apis-for-implementing-rtp-rtsp-for-voip-and-ptt-project) -- this claims to work all the way back to Android 2.3 Gingerbread.